# java stop people from closing

Tags: java, swing

hi i have a full screen program which i dont want people to close unless they have a password i have this code at the moment

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0)
{
    System.out.println("HERE");
    String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the closeword");

    if (inputValue != "closeplz")
    {

    }
}
```

in the if statement i want it to stop the method so that the program doesent close. any help would be greatly aprecheated thanks ste

Comment: What about CTRL+ALT+DEL or CTRL+SHIFT+ESC on Windows?

Comment: killing the running java process won't ask password.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's propably a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

on (or within) the `JFrame` instance. Then the frame will not close unless you do it manually, though `windowClosing()` will still be called. Inside it, you can then conditionally call

```
System.exit(1);
```

which will end the application. Be sure to do any necessary cleanup first.

Comment: @thejh: true, that's the general convention. But GUI apps rarely (if ever) have their return code checked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Closing an Applicaton](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for a simple class to help you with this. You would need to provide the custom close action that prompts the user for the password.

Using your simple example the code would be:

```
Action ca = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JFrame frame = (JFrame)e.getSource();

        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the closeword");


        if (! inputValue.equals("closeplz"))
        {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
};

CloseListener cl = new CloseListener(ca);
```